# Runtime for calculating the factorial of 14 is equal for both iterative and recursive

Tags: python, runtime

If we run the given code snippet to find the runtimes for calculating the factorial of 14 is almost equal for both iterative and recursive 995-999 times out of 1000. There was something oddly beautiful about it.

```
import time

def factorialIterative(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        result = result * i
    return result

def factorialRecursive(n):
   if n == 1:
       return n
   else:
       return n*factorialRecursive(n-1)

def findRunTime(functionToCheck,parameter):
    startingTime = time.time()
    functionToCheck(parameter)
    endingTime = time.time()
    return endingTime-startingTime

count = 0

for i in range(1000):
    if (findRunTime(factorialIterative,14)-findRunTime(factorialRecursive,14)<0.00001 and findRunTime(factorialIterative,14)-findRunTime(factorialRecursive,14)>-0.00001):
        count=count+1

print(count)
```

My instinct says that it has something to do with space because up till 14 we see that the recursive is faster than the iterative which is counter intuitive as they have the same time complexities and after 14, iterative takes over as compared to recursive.
I'd say this is because of the size of the call stack matches the size of the `result` variable.

I'm almost certain that my reasoning is incorrect which is why I'd love to hear if someone can give a good explanation about why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

In my testing the recursive approach is significantly slower that the straightforward iterative approach.

Using *time.time()* is not likely to be very accurate for short durations.

The Python version, operating system and hardware may have a significant impact on the results.

```
import timeit

N = 14

def factorialIterative(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        result = result * i
    return result

def factorialRecursive(n):
   if n == 1:
       return n
   else:
       return n*factorialRecursive(n-1)

# ensure that both implementation return the same results
assert factorialIterative(N) == factorialRecursive(N)

for func in factorialIterative, factorialRecursive:
    print(func.__name__, timeit.timeit(lambda: func(N)))
```

**Output:**

```
factorialIterative 0.6722345929993025
factorialRecursive 1.3617302580005344
```

**Platform:**

```
Python 3.10.5
macOS 12.4
3 GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W
32GB RAM 2666 MHz DDR4
```

**Note:**

```
math.factorial is **much** faster
```

Comment: This code does not work for me :(

Comment: @Vayun In what way does it not work?